# select box customization in IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have customized select box arrow using below css attributes.It works for other browsers except IE9.After customized, two overlapped arrows can be found in IE9 which are default arrow and applied custom arrow.Is there any other way to customize select box for all browsers?

```css
select {
  appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  -o-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  background: url('../img/icons/list-benifit-drop.png') no-repeat;
  background-position: 100%;
  text-indent: 0.01px;
  text-overflow: "";
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Cheers !!!

Comment: Add your `html`

Comment: hi, I have added HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using different stylesheets files for different browsers and overwrite the style for the select box.

```
<!--/!--[if lte IE 9]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css_for_IE9.css">
<!--[endif]--//-->
```

Aslo, you can use Bootstrap and customize their select box.